# How to declare variables properly

Tags: c++

I am supposed to write a program that has an array of 20 integers and it needs to call a function that uses a linear search algorithm to locate one of the values and another function that uses a binary search algorithm to locate the same value. Both functions need to keep count of the number of comparisons it makes and display them.

I need to use the following prototypes :

```
int linearSearch(const int arr[], int size, int value)
int binarySearch(const int array[], int numElems, int value)
```

Once I compiled the program I get a warning that states

> variable 'position1' set but not used".

I have initialized the variable but I am unable to find the problem.

```cpp
//Function for linear search
int linearSearch(const int arr[], int size, int value)
{
    int index = 0;
    int position1 = -1;
    bool found = false;
    int counter1 = 0;

    while( index < size && !found)
    {
        if(arr[index] == value)
        {
            found = true;
            position1 = index;
        }
        index ++;
        counter1++;
    }
    return counter1;
}
```

Comment: You only ever give position1 a value, you don't actually access that value anywhere in the function. You could remove `int position1 = -1;` and `position1 = index;` and the function would run the same as it does with them.

Comment: Well, that's not an error, just a warning and if you look closely it's a _fair_ warning, possibly indicating some logic flaw. So, there you declared a `position1`  variable, stored something there and _definitely never used that "something" or the variable afterwards_ . It could be `position1 = 42` or `position1 = 666` written instead, the function behaviour wouldn't change. Compiler warns you about that strangeness, that's why you see the warning.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is right. You never actually use `position1`. Let's take a look at all the places you access to `position1`:

```
//Function for linear search
//int linearSearch(const int arr[], int size, int value)
//{
//    int index = 0;
      int position1 = -1;
//    bool found = false;
//    int counter1 = 0;
//
//    while( index < size && !found)
//    {
//        if(arr[index] == value)
//        {
//            found = true;
              position1 = index;
//        }
//        index ++;
//        counter1++;
//    }
//    return counter1;
//}
```

You initialize the value of `position1`, then assign it with a potentially meaningful value calculated by `position1 = index;`

Now tell me: where do you read the value of `position1`?

Nowhere in the function you actually read the value of `position1`, nor do you return it's value. In fact, it's value could be `100000000` or `-2`, your program will behave the same, since you never read the value. In fact, you could **entirely remove the variable** and your program will still behave exactly the same!

The compiler knows that because `position1` is a local variable. The scope of the variable `position1` is only within the function.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is just letting you know that you've declared a variable that is not being used. The program can still compile as it is a warning rather than a build time or run time error.